# Example for receiving a file through API Gateway and uploading it to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I was wondering had an example of this, as I have struggled trying to figure this out.

Comment: Why do you wish to send a file via API Gateway to Amazon S3? It would be much easier for an API Gateway function to provide temporary credentials, then have the client upload directly to S3.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in the past, but using lambda (which I'm guessing is OK for you, as you tagged this question with lambda). This is an older one and uses node.js 6.10. I haven't checked if it works in later versions.

This example takes a file in body of API call, names it, saves it in S3 and returns the new name of the file. I used the event id and content type header to create a filename.

This is my body mapping template from API Gateway (I set up several, one for each content type I accepted):

```
{
    "body": "$input.body",
    "requestId": "$context.requestId",
    "contentType" : "$input.params('Content-Type')"
}
```

And this is my lambda code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var contentType = event.contentType;
    var file = new Buffer(event.body, 'base64');
    var fileType = (contentType.split('/'))[1];
    console.log(fileType);
    var key = event.requestId + '.' + fileType;
    var param = {Bucket: 'aBucket', Key : key,  Body: file};
    s3.putObject(param, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else console.log(data);           // successful response
        console.log('actually done!');
        context.succeed(key);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out, and yeah I wanted to use Lambda.